# Prove that preimage of any closed subset in $\mathbb{R}$ is closed subset in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous function. Prove that preimage of any closed subset in $\mathbb{R}$ is closed subset in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

I have no idea where should I start

Comment: Do you know that $f$ is continuous if and only if for any sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ converging to $x$, the sequence $(f(x_n))$ converges to $f(x)$ ? And that a set is closed in $\mathbb R^n $ if an only if for any convergent sequence of elements in set, the limit is also contained in the set? See if you can go from there.

Comment: Assume that $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is closed. Then $\mathbb{R} \setminus C$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. We have by the continuity of $f$ that $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \setminus C) = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) \setminus f^{-1}(C) = \mathbb{R}^n \setminus  f^{-1}(C)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. This implies $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: You shall tell us which definition of continuity is used. Probably the $\epsilon-\delta$-definition?